# Is modifying HUD possible?

Tags: killing-floor

I've highlighted the  HUD elements I consider as "non-essential" in the following screenshot (additionally the background image for the wave counter on the top right corner):

[image: HUD]

Some HUD decorations can be removed by enabling "light HUD" option in [HUD settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdB0T.png) (enabled in the screenshot).